What might prevent a Keysight scope being sold to EU consumers?
I cannot afford a Keysight HD304MSO scope, but that doesn't stop them sending me spam trying to sell me one.
Mouser UK tell me that I can't have one anyway. "Product available only to OEM/EMS and design business customers. Product is not shipped to consumers in the EU or the UK".
The mouser US site mentions no such restriction.
This is a brand new product. What might prevent it being sold to EU consumers, but allowed in the US?

Most likely basic things like warranty requirements, missing safety warning sheets or missing stickers on the backside.

Might not have CE marking visible on the unit, might be they don't want to deal with import taxes.

If you are a consumer in the EU, you have consumer rights mandated by EU and  products sold to consumers must comply to all rules for consumer equipment.
It does not matter if the product is a 100 EUR mobile phone, 1000 EUR computer, or a 10000 EUR specialized tool such as an oscilloscope.
Also the distributor may have a deal with the importer that allows only dealing with businesses, and some other distributor may have a deal to sell them in retail stores.

yeah my guess is exactly Justme's last point: keysight having a distribution agreement with Mouser that says that Mouser isn't to sell the scope to end users in some markets. Why? Money reasons (they want to sell directly there, they try to kill the scope series and the EU/UK distribution contract was the first where they could make the distributor stop, they have negotiated a higher margin with another EU distributor, scope is fast enough to need costly export documentation, so for this very cheap one they're only willing to do it for important customers)

I’m voting to close this question because it's about Politics/Export-Controls, not Electrical Engineering.

No, please, I'm looking for a specific reaon why this scope does not meet consumer requirements, which is an engineering decision.

You don't know that it's an engineering decision to not sell that scope to consumers in the EU or UK - you're speculating. In fact your 'accepted' answer says that it's not an engineering decision.

RS-Components lists the scope as available but with warning to
REACH Regulation (EC) No 1907/2006
due to 1,2-dimethoxyethane,ethylene glycol dimethyl ether

Oh, shucks. It looks like I'll have to make do with being unable to afford something from Rhode & Schwarz instead.
Thanks very much, great find!
